# Is truncated normal CDF a decreasing function of $\mu$?

Tags: calculus, statistics

Suppose $F(x;\mu,\sigma^2,0,1)$ is the CDF of a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ random variable truncated on the unit interval $(0,1)$. I'd like to show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mu} F(x;\mu,\sigma^2,0,1)  < 0$. I can empirically see this to be true but have difficulty analytically proving it. Please note that the statement might not be true if the support is not on the unit interval. The analytic form of $F$ is as follows, $$F(x;\mu,\sigma^2,0,1)=\frac{\Phi(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})-\Phi(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma})}{\Phi(\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma})-\Phi(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma})},$$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal CDF.